# PBO Can't use Select Single

Tags: abap

In my code below, if I use `Select Single * From...` it gives a syntax error,you should use Select * From...

If I use `Select * From..` it tells me `Field COUNTRY is not a key field`(if I comment the field country it says statement IF is not defined)

If I use the above query it tells me

> Unprocessed components with POSIT.

GOAL:I am trying to make the field **z2004_03-persno1** Uneditable

Code:

```
LOOP AT   GT_TC_01
       WITH CONTROL TC_0800
       CURSOR TC_0800-CURRENT_LINE.
    MODULE TC_0800_GET_LINES.

    SELECT *
    FROM YPM_USERS
    INTO DATA(WA_YPM_USERS) 
    WHERE UNAME = SY-UNAME
    AND  COUNTRY = 'BG'.

*      IF SY-SUBRC EQ 0.
      IF SCREEN-NAME = 'z2004_03-persno1'.
        SCREEN-INPUT = '0'.
        MODIFY SCREEN.
      ELSE.
        SCREEN-INPUT = 1.
        MODIFY SCREEN.
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.

  ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: It is not possible to use SELECT in PBO/PAI. You need to use screen statements and namely MODULE in this case: https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenabap_dynpros_dynpro_statements.htm

Comment: @JozsefSzikszai Thanks a thousand!

Answer (score 6):

Simply because `BPO` and `PAI` blocks are not in `ABAP` language. So you can't use `ABAP` statements in this blocks. Only a few key words are authorized in dynpro flow logic.

Check [dynpro flow logic](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abendynpro_flow_logic_glosry.htm) .

Comment: stop copying answers from SAP forum,I already checked that and your answer does not provide an answer its more suitable for a comment

Comment: @PureAbap Enea's answer is 100% answer to your case. SELECT statement is invalid in PAI/PBO and cannot be used.